# Positioning a div to the right of its containing div

Tags: html, css

I know this question will sound very basic but i just am not able to fix it.I have got a div container and im trying to position the a child div to the right.I tried positioning the container div with relative and then positioning the child div with absolute,but the parent div loses its width.[image]

please have a look at the image above,i need the div1 to position itself right of the divContainer. I have got other nested divs in divContainer, i need only div1 to be postioned on the right.

```
div#divContainer{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 0px;
    width:1000px;
    background:#666;
    position:relative;

}
div#div1{
    height:45px;width:200px;
    background:yellow;
    position:absolute;

}
```

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divContainer">
            <div id="div1"></div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that #div1 is a nav type div, you should just float it to the side you want it.

```
div#div1{
  height:45px;width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  float:right;
}
```

This will position it absolutely within your document. If you're having trouble with this, you may want to spend some time reading some good resources about CSS positioning. [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/) has great resources for CSS.

Comment: This should work for you, just add content inside of #divContainer after #div1 and you'll see that the container expands to fit that content.

Answer (score 2):

`#divContainer` shouldn’t lose its width based on your description, but it will lose its height if all its child divs are absolutely positioned.

The best method for positioning `#div1` depends on whether you want it to affect the position of the other chid divs. If so, apply `float: right;` to `#div1`. If not, `position: absolute;` is the way to go; you may want to add padding to the right of `#divContainer` so that `#div1` doesn’t sit on top of the other child divs.

Is this what you’re aiming for?

- http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/J9vQF/

Comment: thanks for ur answer,i have edited the CSS code.Could you please check the CSS code or run it in ur browser? the parent div is losing its width.

Comment: @manraj82: sure; have you got a link to the edited version? I’m a bit new to JSFiddle; I think you might need to hit “save” or something after editing.

Comment: thanks,i had a look at ur code.why is that when i delete div2,div3 and div4, the divContainer disappears[its losing its width].Sorry just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: @manraj82: ah sure — it doesn’t lose its width, it loses its height. The effect is the same: it disappears. `<div>`s get their height from their contents; if they have no contents, they have no height. When elements are positioned absolutely, they are removed from the document’s flow, and are no longer considered contents of their parent for purposes of calculating height. Thus you might well be better off with Matthew’s suggestion of using `float` instead.