# How to place button on right side in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a simple UI for a webapp using React and Ant Design. I would like to place a Button at the top right of the screen. My component render function looks something like this:

```
return (
    <div style={{something here?}}>
        <div style={{something else here?}}>
            <Button>Logout</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
           {Main components here}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

I have tried adding various things to the outer and/or inner dics and have not been able to move the button to the right - it always stays on the left. How do I make it move to the right?

Comment: Use the float property of style and set it to right:
<div style="float:right"/>

Comment: direction, float, flex, position pick one..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning a div to the right of its containing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450764/positioning-a-div-to-the-right-of-its-containing-div)

Answer (score 6):

```
return (
    <div style={{}}>
        <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
            <Button>Logout</Button>
        </div>
       <div style={{clear: 'both'}}></div>
        <div>
           {Main components here}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Try that, also, this is not a React question, it should be tagged CSS

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use flex-box

```css
#button{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='button'>
    <button> some button</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> Main conent section </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set buttons display to *inline-block* or *inline*.
This will make the button to behave like normal text.
After the above step set the buttons immediate divs text-align property to *right*. 
Hope this helps.

`<div style="text-align:right">
 <button style="display:inline-block">click me</button>
 </div>`

Comment: I don't know what you are saying. Can you please be more specific with a simple example?

Comment: Was typing from my cell-phone. Check the answer now, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>

      <Button onClick={() => this.logout()}>
        Logout
      </Button>

</div>
```

Or

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <Button style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}  onClick={() => this.logout()}>
      Logout
    </Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easly create a class in your style file as follows :

```
 .flex_end   {
    @include styleclass('flex justify-content-end');
    }
```

then add it in your button definition like this :

```
 <div className='col-12 p-0 pb-1 flex_end'>
    <Button                            
    icon='pi pi-arrow-up-left'
    className='p-button-sm '
    onClick={() => onSelectPrinter()}
    type='button'
    />
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple and useful. You need to use just-content and set its value to 'flex-end'.

```
return (
    <div>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justify-content: 'flex-end'}}>
            <Button>Logout</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
           {Main components here}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.